# Navigation Menu from database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC and I'm generating a menu from database.

I managed to make it work but I have a problem: It only works when the action is index, because the database function is in `IActionResult Index()` method.

How can I fix this problem? My navigation view in in the `_layout.chtml`.

How can I make to call the function before rendering the layout? Will this have effect on performance, because it will query database every time?

Comment: You could use a ViewComponent http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/294/view-components-in-asp-net-core-mvc

Comment: @AlexandrePires thanks. it was easy. hahahah. thanks dude, but i cant mark your comment as answers. And will there be a performance hit?

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead and your question is more likely to be found by people who can help you with the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to create a ViewComponent (as see [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/294/view-components-in-asp-net-core-mvc)).

You simply would to invoke it in the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: will there be a performance hit because every time the layout was render, it will query the database.

Comment: You could use (inject) a IMemoryCache inside the view component in the case of the navigation doesn't change that often. This way you can reduce the the amount of times the database is called.